# Print index entry name in text

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, makeidx

I have an article document using indexes like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
    This is a text, and it contains the index entry text.\index{text}
    \printindex
\end{document}
```

However, I would like to not type the index entry (here: "text") twice in the source code every time it appears. (As "text" in `\index{text}` does not get printed.)

I would like to use something like `...contains the index entry \some_command{text}` which would both print the text "contains the index entry text" *and* adds "text" to the index.

Comment: It is best to make your own macro for this. say `\newcommand\mindex[1]{#1\index{#1}}`. But remember that indices are not always as simple as just `index this term`, sometimes you need to separate sorting and display for the index (say `\index{latex@\LaTeX}` to have `\LaTeX` sorted under `l` (the handling of `\..` macros depends on the index program being used).

Comment: I agree, best use a macro that also deals with subentries and possibly index formatting commands, which requires several optional arguments. My macro is therefore using \NewDocumentCommand from xparse.

Comment: Why not go for the glossaries-extra package that already includes commands that offer the desired feature?